# How many 6 digits number can be generated using digits 0-9 with repetition of any digit?

Tags: probability

How many 6 digits number can be generated using digits 0-9 with repetition of any digit?

Few Examples:
111111
122222
123333
123456
324222

Comment: $10^6-10^5$....

Comment: work out how many numbers 100000 to 999999 there are without repetition - first off, it starts with a digit from 1 - 9, then you choose 5 digits from 0 - 9 (excluding digit 1 that was chosen) so that is 5 from 9 - then jumbled 5! ways - then you subtract this from count of all numbers 100000 to 999999

Comment: you don't specifically want a repeated digit though? 763920 of 6 digit numbers have a repeated digit, and 136080 have no repeated digit - I make it - total of 900000

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

how many are the numbers between $100000$ and $999999$ ?

Answer (score 0):

By the [Rule of Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), they are $9\cdot 10^5$ if you want that the first digit is different from zero. They are $10^6$ if you allow that the first digit can be zero.